# Can I connect interactive Python Tools for Visual Studio with existing ipython kernel

Tags: visual-studio, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ptvs

I was wondering if it's possible to connect the interactive session in python tools for visual studio to an existing ipython kernel?

I know you can connect a ipython qtconsole (which I assume PTVS is using) to an existing ipython kernel, and I can get the kernel info for an existing notebook via the

```
%connect_info
```

magic.

However I don't know how, or if, you can configure PTVS to start an interactive session that is connected to the existing kernel.

I can see that PTVS has some interactive startup options, and thought that these might help, but haven't got anything to work yet.

[image]

Anyhelp would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not currently possible, but it is one of the major features that are very likely to be done for PTVS 3.0. Please leave your feedback on this GitHub issue:

https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/774